# How to convert the following CSV file to the XML?please help me with either perl or java

Tags: java, perl

please help me ,I am not able come up with proper logic for this CSV conversion to XML.

CSV:

```
,"Section","Title","Description","value range","Link","Array size","Exhaustive","Type","Goal"
,1,"Intra Pred",,,,,,,100
,1.1,"Generics",,,,,,,100
,"1.1.1","mode1.1","TUSizelog2 ","2:5","cg_intra_pred:log2tra",,"Y","CoverPoint",100
,"1.1.2","mode1.2","chroma     ","0:1","cg_intra_pred:ischroma",,"Y","CoverPoint",100
,"1.1.3","mode1.3","slice_ctrl_in.bit_depth_8not10","0:1","cg_intra_pred:bitdepth_8not10",,"Y","CoverPoint",100
,1.2,"Stimulus",,,,,,,100
,"1.2.1","stim1.1","ctrl_in.pu.mode","0:34","cg_intra_pred:pumode",1,"Y","CoverPoint",100
,"1.2.2","stim1.2","ctrl_in.pu.blkx/blky","0:15","cg_intra_pred:tublkx;;cg_intra_pred:tublky;;cg_intra_pred:publkx;;cg_intra_pred:publky",1,"Y","CoverPoint",100
,"1.2.3","stim1.3","ctrl_in.tu.neigh_avail","0:31","cg_intra_pred:neighavail1;;cg_intra_pred:neighavail2;;cg_intra_pred:neighavail3;;cg_intra_pred:neighavail4;;cg_intra_pred:neighavail5",1,"Y","CoverPoint",100
,"1.2.4","stim1.4","refAbove_in ; ;;refLeft_in; ;;refAboveMode_in; ;;refLeftMode_in","0:255/1023;;0:255/1023;;0:34;;0:34","cg_intrapred_abv;;cg_intrapred_left;;cg_intrapred_mode;;","2*Tusize;;(2*TUsize)+1;;TUsize/4;;TUsize/4;;","Y","CoverPoint",100
```

XML expected format:

```
<Project>
  <name>demo</name>
  <description>System Feature list</description>
  <user>sandeepg</user>
  <group>
    <name>Intra Pred</name>
    <user>sandeepg</user>
    <description />
    <pcent_required>100</pcent_required>
    <priority />
  </group>
  <group>
    <name>Generics</name>
    <user>sandeepg</user>
    <description />
    <pcent_required>100</pcent_required>
    <priority />
    <cover_task>
      <name>mode1.1</name>
      <description>TUSizelog2</description>
      <kind>CoverPoint</kind>
      <pcent_required>100</pcent_required>
      <map />
      <priority />
      <uid />
      <pid />
      <sign_off>false</sign_off>
      <obsolete>false</obsolete>
      <manual_sign_off>false</manual_sign_off>
      <item_name />
      <aggregation>INSTANCE</aggregation>
    </cover_task>
    <cover_task>
      <name>mode1.2</name>
      <description>chroma</description>
      <kind>CoverPoint</kind>
      <pcent_required>100</pcent_required>
      <map />
      <priority />
      <uid />
      <pid />
      <sign_off>false</sign_off>
      <obsolete>false</obsolete>
      <manual_sign_off>false</manual_sign_off>
      <item_name />
      <aggregation>INSTANCE</aggregation>
    </cover_task>
    <cover_task>
      <name>mode1.3</name>
      <description>slice_ctrl_in.bit_depth_8not10</description>
      <kind>CoverPoint</kind>
      <pcent_required>100</pcent_required>
      <map />
      <priority />
      <uid />
      <pid />
      <sign_off>false</sign_off>
      <obsolete>false</obsolete>
      <manual_sign_off>false</manual_sign_off>
      <item_name />
      <aggregation>INSTANCE</aggregation>
    </cover_task>
  </group>  <!-- This tag should come -->
  <group>
    <name>Stimulus</name>
    <user>sandeepg</user>
    <description />
    <pcent_required>100</pcent_required>
    <priority />
    <cover_task>
      <name>stim1.1</name>
      <description>ctrl_in.pu.mode</description>
      <kind>CoverPoint</kind>
      <pcent_required>100</pcent_required>
      <map />
      <priority />
      <uid />
      <pid />
      <sign_off>false</sign_off>
      <obsolete>false</obsolete>
      <manual_sign_off>false</manual_sign_off>
      <item_name />
      <aggregation>INSTANCE</aggregation>
    </cover_task>
    <cover_task>
      <name>stim1.2</name>
      <description>ctrl_in.pu.blkx/blky</description>
      <kind>CoverPoint</kind>
      <pcent_required>100</pcent_required>
      <map />
      <priority />
      <uid />
      <pid />
      <sign_off>false</sign_off>
      <obsolete>false</obsolete>
      <manual_sign_off>false</manual_sign_off>
      <item_name />
      <aggregation>INSTANCE</aggregation>
    </cover_task>
    <cover_task>
      <name>stim1.3</name>
      <description>ctrl_in.tu.neigh_avail</description>
      <kind>CoverPoint</kind>
      <pcent_required>100</pcent_required>
      <map />
      <priority />
      <uid />
      <pid />
      <sign_off>false</sign_off>
      <obsolete>false</obsolete>
      <manual_sign_off>false</manual_sign_off>
      <item_name />
      <aggregation>INSTANCE</aggregation>
    </cover_task>
    <cover_task>
      <name>stim1.4</name>
      <description>refAbove_in ; ;;refLeft_in; ;;refAboveMode_in; ;;refLeftMode_in</description>
      <kind>CoverPoint</kind>
      <pcent_required>100</pcent_required>
      <map />
      <priority />
      <uid />
      <pid />
      <sign_off>false</sign_off>
      <obsolete>false</obsolete>
      <manual_sign_off>false</manual_sign_off>
      <item_name />
      <aggregation>INSTANCE</aggregation>
    </cover_task>
  </group>
</Project>
```

My Script:

```
#!usr/bin/perl
my $project_description = "System Feature list";
my $project_username    = $ENV{USER};
if ( @ARGV < 3 ) {
    print "\nRequired arguments are not provided.\n";
    print "syntax is \n\tCSV-XML_Conversion <input_file&path> <output_file&path>  ";
    exit(1);
}

my $input_path   = $ARGV[0];
my $output_path  = $ARGV[1];
my $project_name = $ARGV[2];

open( XML_WR_File, " > $output_path " );
open( RD_File, "$input_path " ) or die "$! ";
readline(RD_File);

print XML_WR_File " \<Project\> \n ";
print XML_WR_File " \t \<name\>$project_name \<\/name\> \n ";
print XML_WR_File " \t \<description\>$project_description \<\/description\> \n ";
print XML_WR_File " \t \<user\>$project_username \<\/user\> \n ";

#print XML_WR_File " \t \<group\> \n ";

while ( $line = <RD_File> ) {
    chop;
    $line_count++;
    $line =~ s/" // g;
    $line =~ s/(^\s+|\s+$)//g;
    @field = split( ',', $line );
    $size_of_array = @field;

    if ( $field[8] eq m/\s/ ) {
        print XML_WR_File "\t\t\<group\> \n";
        print XML_WR_File "\t\t\<name\>$field[2]\<\/name\> \n";
        print XML_WR_File "\t\t\<user\>$project_username\<\/user\> \n";
        print XML_WR_File "\t\t\<description\>$field[3]\<\/description\> \n";
        print XML_WR_File"\t\t\<pcent_required\>$field[9]\<\/pcent_require\>\n";
        print XML_WR_File "\t\t\<priority\>\<\/priority\>\n";

        #print XML_WR_File "\t\<group\> \n";
    }
    elsif ( $field[8] =~ m/\w/ ) {
        $type_count++;
        print XML_WR_File "\t\t\t\<cover_task\>\n";
        print XML_WR_File "\t\t\t\t\<name\>$field[2]\<\/name\>\n";
        print XML_WR_File "\t\t\t\t\<description\>$field[3]\<\/description\>\n";
        print XML_WR_File "\t\t\t\t\<kind\>$field[8]\<\/kind\>\n";
        print XML_WR_File "\t\t\t\t\<pcent_required\>$field[9]\<\/pcent_required\>\n";
        print XML_WR_File "\t\t\t\t\<map\>\<\/map\>\n";
        print XML_WR_File "\t\t\t\t\<priority\>\<\/priority\>\n";
        print XML_WR_File "\t\t\t\t\<uid\>\<\/uid\>\n";
        print XML_WR_File "\t\t\t\t\<pid\>\<\/pid\>\n";
        print XML_WR_File "\t\t\t\t\<sign_off\>false\<\/sign_off\>\n";
        print XML_WR_File "\t\t\t\t\<obsolete\>false\<\/obsolete\>\n";
        print XML_WR_File "\t\t\t\t\<manual_sign_off\>false\<\/manual_sign_off\>\n";
        print XML_WR_File "\t\t\t\t\<item_name\><\/item_name\>\n";
        print XML_WR_File "\t\t\t\t\<aggregation\>INSTANCE\<\/aggregation\>\n";
        print XML_WR_File "\t\t\t\<\/cover_task\>\n";
    }
}
print XML_WR_File "\t\<\/group\>\n";
print XML_WR_File "\<\/Project\>\n";
```

Comment: Have you considered using modules to do this? You have modules that parse CSV (e.g. [`Parse::CSV`](http://search.cpan.org/~adamk/Parse-CSV-2.00/lib/Parse/CSV.pm)), modules that generate XML (e.g. [XML::LibXML](http://search.cpan.org/~shlomif/XML-LibXML-2.0116/LibXML.pod)), and even a module (I don't know how flexible it is) that converts CSV to XML directly: [XML::CSV](http://search.cpan.org/~isterin/XML-CSV-0.15/CSV.pm).

Comment: Thank you for arranging my text here and yes I have tried using TEXT::CSV ,but I don't have the permission to do so on target machine,so I need do it without any modules :-) @scozy

Comment: An easy solution if you cannot install modules would be to download a pure-perl module. Here, for instance, is [Text::CSV_PP](http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/MAKAMAKA/Text-CSV-1.32/lib/Text/CSV_PP.pm). Wherever you are launching your script from, create a `Text` subdirectory, and save `CSV_PP.pm` there, then you can `use Text::CSV_PP`. Not great, but convenient.

Comment: yes I feel doing so would be great,but in the csv ,please see that there are indexes,1 is feature,1.1 is sub-feature and 1.1.1 is a goal,in this way I have to extract csv contents and put em in feature-sub_feature-goals hierarchy in XML ,and there are 2 logics ,using indexes or else checking type,what I have done in my script,is by using type logic ,but in that I need to close the group tag after every last goal ,before any feature...this seems to be a problem :(

Answer (score 0):

I would break things up into print qq blocks if you want to do it all manually:

```
my $output = "";

#do some stuff ...

  if ( $field[8] eq m/\s/ ) {
  $output .= qq()
  <group\>
        <name\>$field[2]\<\/name\>
        <user\>$project_username\<\/user\>
        <description\>$field[3]\<\/description\>
        <pcent_required\>$field[9]\<\/pcent_require\>
        <priority\>\<\/priority\>
    <group\>
    }

# at theend $out has your whole file.
```

Also with qq you don't need all the funk `\/`

I made a quick perl script that you should run and see for your self:

```
print qq(

<Project>
  <name>demo</name>
  <description>System Feature list</description>
  <user>sandeepg</user>
  <group>
    <name>Intra Pred</name>
    <user>sandeepg</user>
    <description />
    <pcent_required>100</pcent_required>
    <priority />
  </group>
  <group>
    <name>Generics</name>
    <user>sandeepg</user>
    <description />
    <pcent_required>100</pcent_required>
    <priority />
    <cover_task>
      <name>mode1.1</name>
      <description>TUSizelog2</description>
      <kind>CoverPoint</kind>
      <pcent_required>100</pcent_required>
      <map />
      <priority />
      <uid />
      <pid />
      <sign_off>false</sign_off>
      <obsolete>false</obsolete>
      <manual_sign_off>false</manual_sign_off>
      <item_name />
      <aggregation>INSTANCE</aggregation>
    </cover_task>
    <cover_task>
      <name>mode1.2</name>
      <description>chroma</description>
      <kind>CoverPoint</kind>
      <pcent_required>100</pcent_required>
      <map />
      <priority />
      <uid />
      <pid />
      <sign_off>false</sign_off>
      <obsolete>false</obsolete>
      <manual_sign_off>false</manual_sign_off>
      <item_name />
      <aggregation>INSTANCE</aggregation>
    </cover_task>
    <cover_task>
      <name>mode1.3</name>
      <description>slice_ctrl_in.bit_depth_8not10</description>
      <kind>CoverPoint</kind>
      <pcent_required>100</pcent_required>
      <map />
      <priority />
      <uid />
      <pid />
      <sign_off>false</sign_off>
      <obsolete>false</obsolete>
      <manual_sign_off>false</manual_sign_off>
      <item_name />
      <aggregation>INSTANCE</aggregation>
    </cover_task>
  </group>
  <!-- This tag should come -->
  <group>
    <name>Stimulus</name>
    <user>sandeepg</user>
    <description />
    <pcent_required>100</pcent_required>
    <priority />
    <cover_task>
      <name>stim1.1</name>
      <description>ctrl_in.pu.mode</description>
      <kind>CoverPoint</kind>
      <pcent_required>100</pcent_required>
      <map />
      <priority />
      <uid />
      <pid />
      <sign_off>false</sign_off>
      <obsolete>false</obsolete>
      <manual_sign_off>false</manual_sign_off>
      <item_name />
      <aggregation>INSTANCE</aggregation>
    </cover_task>
    <cover_task>
      <name>stim1.2</name>
      <description>ctrl_in.pu.blkx/blky</description>
      <kind>CoverPoint</kind>
      <pcent_required>100</pcent_required>
      <map />
      <priority />
      <uid />
      <pid />
      <sign_off>false</sign_off>
      <obsolete>false</obsolete>
      <manual_sign_off>false</manual_sign_off>
      <item_name />
      <aggregation>INSTANCE</aggregation>
    </cover_task>
    <cover_task>
      <name>stim1.3</name>
      <description>ctrl_in.tu.neigh_avail</description>
      <kind>CoverPoint</kind>
      <pcent_required>100</pcent_required>
      <map />
      <priority />
      <uid />
      <pid />
      <sign_off>false</sign_off>
      <obsolete>false</obsolete>
      <manual_sign_off>false</manual_sign_off>
      <item_name />
      <aggregation>INSTANCE</aggregation>
    </cover_task>
    <cover_task>
      <name>stim1.4</name>
      <description>refAbove_in ; ;;refLeft_in; ;;refAboveMode_in; ;;refLeftMode_in</description>
      <kind>CoverPoint</kind>
      <pcent_required>100</pcent_required>
      <map />
      <priority />
      <uid />
      <pid />
      <sign_off>false</sign_off>
      <obsolete>false</obsolete>
      <manual_sign_off>false</manual_sign_off>
      <item_name />
      <aggregation>INSTANCE</aggregation>
    </cover_task>
  </group>
</Project>
);
```

**strong text**

```
C:\Temp>perl test.pl


<Project>
  <name>demo</name>
  <description>System Feature list</description>
  <user>sandeepg</user>
  <group>
    <name>Intra Pred</name>
    <user>sandeepg</user>
    <description />
    <pcent_required>100</pcent_required>
    <priority />
  </group>
  <group>
    <name>Generics</name>
    <user>sandeepg</user>
    <description />
    <pcent_required>100</pcent_required>
    <priority />

    ... (etc.)
```

You might want to use a module but usually when I'm doing quick XML stuff I do it similar to this.

Comment: thank you ,but this isn't what I expected,I need to write a perl script for the above type of CSVs to get em converted to XMLs.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that you use `Text::CSV` for parsing the CSV file. But since you cannot use it, you could try:

```
#! /usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

open(my $xml,">", "file.xml");
open(my $csv,"<", "file.csv" );
readline($csv);
my $project_username="sandeepg";
my $line_count=0;

while (my $line=<$csv> ) {
    chop $line;
    $line_count++;
    $line =~ s/" //g;
    $line =~ s/(^\s+|\s+$)//g;
    my @field = split( ',', $line );
    my $size_of_array = @field;

    if ( $field[8] =~ m/^\s*$/ ) {
        print $xml "\t\t\<group\> \n";
        print $xml "\t\t\<name\>$field[2]\<\/name\> \n";
        print $xml "\t\t\<user\>$project_username\<\/user\> \n";
        print $xml "\t\t\<description\>$field[3]\<\/description\> \n";
        print $xml "\t\t\<pcent_required\>$field[9]\<\/pcent_require\>\n";
        print $xml "\t\t\<priority\>\<\/priority\>\n";
    }
    elsif ( $field[8] =~ m/\w/ ) {
        print $xml "\t\t\t\<cover_task\>\n";
        print $xml "\t\t\t\t\<name\>$field[2]\<\/name\>\n";
        print $xml "\t\t\t\t\<description\>$field[3]\<\/description\>\n";
        print $xml "\t\t\t\t\<kind\>$field[8]\<\/kind\>\n";
        print $xml "\t\t\t\t\<pcent_required\>$field[9]\<\/pcent_required\>\n";
        print $xml "\t\t\t\t\<map\>\<\/map\>\n";
        print $xml "\t\t\t\t\<priority\>\<\/priority\>\n";
        print $xml "\t\t\t\t\<uid\>\<\/uid\>\n";
        print $xml "\t\t\t\t\<pid\>\<\/pid\>\n";
        print $xml "\t\t\t\t\<sign_off\>false\<\/sign_off\>\n";
        print $xml "\t\t\t\t\<obsolete\>false\<\/obsolete\>\n";
        print $xml "\t\t\t\t\<manual_sign_off\>false\<\/manual_sign_off\>\n";
        print $xml "\t\t\t\t\<item_name\><\/item_name\>\n";
        print $xml "\t\t\t\t\<aggregation\>INSTANCE\<\/aggregation\>\n";
        print $xml "\t\t\t\<\/cover_task\>\n";
    }
}
print $xml "\t\<\/group\>\n";
print $xml "\<\/Project\>\n";
```